# Should the usage message go to stderr or stdout?

Tags: command-line

Should the usage message which is printed with e.g.

```
 command -?
```

of a Unix command go to stderr or stdout, and why? Should it go to the same place if the user makes a mistake with an option?

Comment: Additional note: don't use -? use --help and -h 

Because --help and -h are standard and because -? will can be interpreted by the shell.

Comment: @richard This is an excellent point. Fun trick (in bash): `touch -- -l; ls -?` — you actually get a long listing as if you'd passed `-l` to ls.

Comment: @richard. When you don't know whether the command accept GNU-style long options or may support a `-h` option for other thing than a help message, then `'-?'` (with the quotes) or `-:` give you a good chance to get an error (and usage) message since `:` and `?` can't be valid options for anything using `getopt(3)`.

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas. If I understand your comment correctly, you are writing from the perspective of a user of a program, this question I think is from the perspective of someone writing a program.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It should go to stdout, so you can type:

```
command --help | less
```

This is also recommended by the [Gnu Coding Standards on `--help`](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/_002d_002dhelp.html).

On the other hand, the usage message that you get when you use an invalid option or omit a required argument should go to stderr, because it's an error message, and you don't want it to feed into the next command in a pipeline.

When you use `--help`, the usage message is the normal and expected output of the command.  Therefore, it goes to stdout, so it can be piped to another command, like `less` or `grep`.

When you say `command --bogus-option | other-command`, you don't want the usage message going to stdout, because it's now unexpected output that should not be processed by `other-command`.  Also, if the output of `--help` is more than a handful of lines, then the usage error message should only contain a summary of the `--help` output, and refer the user to `--help` for additional details.

Comment: It's a bit confusing to have two different output streams for the same message depending on something isn't it?

Comment: Perhaps, but they're not necessarily the same message.  If the output of `--help` is more than a few lines, then the usage message produced by an invalid option should be just a short summary saying to use `--help` to see the complete information.

Comment: +1 - this is 100% correct, and I don't see any room for disagreement here.

Comment: Is it safe to assume one should do likewise with the command's exit status? eg 0 if `--help` was explicitly asked for, otherwise >0.