# Is there a standard how commands that launch other commands treat shell constructs like redirects?

Tags: shell

Is there an easy way to what the following commands will do?

```
watch foo 2>/dev/null | tr ' ' '-'
strace foo 2>/dev/null | tr ' ' '-'
something_else foo 2>/dev/null | tr ' ' '-'
```

Is there a common expectation how `something_else` should behave? Are there shell constructs that can disambiguate these commands (like which program's output is redirected)?

Comment: Do you have something specific in mind about those commands, or is there some reason you picked those two and not e.g. `sh -c foo 2>/dev/null | tr ' ' '-'`? In general, a command might do what ever it needs to do to complete its task, so it's hard to expect anything about `something_else` without knowing what it does. The same goes for `watch` and `strace`, but they have man pages and other documentation that tells us what they do.

Comment: I have edited my answer a little bit. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: In UNIX, a program's open files are stored in a table as numbers called file descriptors (fd's).  If a program wants to, eg write to a file that it has opened, it gives the kernel some bytes and the fd and the kernel will do the work.  By convention programs should always emit error messages to a specific already open file with file descriptor 2.  When the shell runs `something_else` in the way ur sample code does, it arranges for `something_else`'s fd, 2, to be open to a pseudo file that discards whatever's written to it.  BTW, this convention causes fd 2 to be named standard error.

Comment: @sevo ^ this is only common expectation you have have of line 3 in your sample code, and even then, it depends on `something_else` conforming to the standard error convention.  In reality, it could emit errors anywhere, but it *should* only emit them to file descriptor 2, the standard error stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

> Is there a common expectation how something_else should behave?

Yes, as a regular command. The shell doesn't understand `command1 command2` as two commands, it's one command and one argument (even if it may be a name of a valid binary found in `/bin` for example). It's the `command1` that later runs `command2` via `exec()` syscall, not the shell.

> Are there shell constructs that can disambiguate these commands (like which program's output is redirected)

No, `someting_else` would not be treated in any special way. As said above, there's no construct other than one command and one argument. It also seems the confusion in this question is that *both* `strace` and `foo` are assumed to be run by the shell, but in fact it's a chain of parent-child processes.

#### How shell processes commands and redirections

Bourne-like shells ( that's `bash`, `dash`, `ksh` ) all follow POSIX rules on how commands are interpreted. [POSIX specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01):'A "simple command" is a sequence of optional variable assignments and redirections, in any sequence, optionally followed by words and redirections, terminated by a control operator.' This can be put into a form:

```
[VAR=foo BAR=baz] command1 [arg1, arg2...] [ n>m ]
```

The general rule is that redirection applies to a command, which would be left most non-assignment word. In your example, `strace` is the command and `foo` is the argument to `strace`. The redirections apply only to the command, not the arguments, that is to `strace`. The `foo` isn't run by the shell, but by `strace`, in which case `foo` becomes a child process of `strace`. Similarly, `somethingelse` would be treated as a command with `foo` as its argument.

#### File descriptors

As far as non built-in commands go, they're a child process of the shell, and child processess inherit shell's file descriptors, so they generally don't manage redirections - they receive "prepackaged" destinations, so as far as `strace` and `2>/dev/null` go, it probably wouldn't care what file descriptor 2 actually is (unless it's actively checking on the source code level). `strace` will still write output to file descriptor 2, but shell already wired-up that file descriptor to point to `/dev/null`.

Because file descriptors are inherited, this also explains why if you do something like `strace stat noexist 2>stracelog.txt` both error streams from both `strace` and `stat` go into the same file. By contrast, some commands allow explicitly specifying destination as one of their options. Thus, with `strace -o tracelog.txt stat noexist 2>stracelog.txt` you only have output from `stat` in the `stracelog.txt` file - even though file descriptor is inherited, now `-o` flag is the property of `strace`, and output is managed by the command even if the file descriptor is inherited.

This also gives us a small hint: in theory commands could "redirect" in the sense of duplicating file descriptors onto existing ones via `dup2()` syscall, which is exactly the same mechanism shells would use, but as far as `>` type of redirection symbols - that's still under shell control and hence only interpreted by the parent shell.

#### Why 2>/dev/null ?

It's generally accepted that diagnostic output goes to `stderr`. In fact we already have two excellent posts on this topic:

- [Do progress reports/logging information belong on stderr or stdout?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/331611/85039)
- [When to use standard error stream in command-line application?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/336983/85039)

`watch` and `strace` in your examples follow the convention, that's all. There's no requirement per se to specify `2>/dev/null` to hide output of such commands.

If you do want to specify redirections for the command that you pass as an argument, to `strace` for example, you'd need to have a shell around it. For instance,

```
strace -f bash -c 'stat /etc/passwd nonexisting 2>/dev/null'
```

Notice the use of `-f` flag, since if your focus is on tracing syscalls as applied to `stat` command, you might not see them without `-f` flag.

Answer (score 2):

The commands themselves do not handle the redirections. When the shell creates a new process in which to run the command, the shell will set up the IO as directed. The command itself just runs without having to care about it.

Your `something_else` command will just emit output to stdout and stderr as usual.

Comment: For further reading, see `LESS='+/SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION' man bash`