# To pass a user input string to check with if-else condition

Tags: linux, shell-script

```
str1="ace"
str2="com"
str3="ros"
$name = readinput(Enter name:)

if [[ "$name" == "$str1" ]]; 
then

run ace.txt
else
if [[ "$name" == "$str2" ]];
then

run commscope.txt
else
if [[ "$name" == "$str3" ]];
then

run rosgenberger.txt
else
echo "no match found"
fi
fi
fi
```

Script is not getting executed, please help.  My desired action should be as follows

- If user input is "ace" --- run ace.txt should be executed
- If user input is "com" --- run commscope.txt should be executed
- If user input is "ros" --- run rosgenberger.txt should be executed.

I am running this script in the path where ace.txt/commscope.txt/rosgenberger.txt scripts are present.

Comment: "_Script is not getting executed_" how are you trying to run it, and from what directory?

Comment: What kind of shell are you using? The `$name = readinput(Enter name:)` instruction certainly looks wrong for most shells I know (space around `=`, command name instead of command substitution ...). I would recommend using  [`shellcheck`](https://shellcheck.net)  to debug your script; the tool is also available standalone on many Linux distributions. Also, please indicate exactly how the "script is not getting executed": is there an error message, or simply unexpected behavior? If so, which? **Please edit your question to address these points, don't reply using comments.**

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to do something like the following:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

printf 'Enter name: ' >&2
read -r name

case $name in
    ace)
        run ace.txt
        ;;
    com)
        run commscope.txt
        ;;
    ros)
        run rosgenberger.txt
        ;;
    *)
        printf 'No match for "%s"\n' "$name"
esac
```

This reads a "name" from the user and executes a command based on the user's response.

In the `bash` shell, you could use something a bit slimmer:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

declare -A map=(
    [ace]=ace.txt
    [com]=commscope.txt
    [ros]=rosgenberger.txt
)

read -p 'Enter name: ' -r name

if [[ -n ${map[$name]} ]]; then
    run "${map[$name]}"
else
    printf 'No match for "%s"\n' "$name"
fi
```

This sets up an associative array with the expected "names" as keys and the corresponding filenames as values.  Depending on the user's input, the correct filename is used with the `run` command.

Most of the time, though, you don't want to interact with the user, but to allow the user to simply provide the input via a command line option.  The following bypasses the interactive prompt for input by using the first argument passed via the command line as the default value for `name`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

name=$1

declare -A map=(
    [ace]=ace.txt
    [com]=commscope.txt
    [ros]=rosgenberger.txt
)

if [[ -z $name ]]; then
    read -p 'Enter name: ' -r name
fi

if [[ -n ${map[$name]} ]]; then
    run "${map[$name]}"
else
    printf 'No match for "%s"\n' "$name"
fi
```

This would be used like this:

```
./myscript ace
```

... for example.  The script would then bypass the interactive question and execute `run ace.txt`.

The code could be slimmed down further by letting variable expansion needed for the `run` command do our error reporting:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

name=$1

declare -A map=(
    [ace]=ace.txt
    [com]=commscope.txt
    [ros]=rosgenberger.txt
)

if [[ -z $name ]]; then
    read -p 'Enter name: ' -r name
fi

run "${map[$name]?Name $name not matched}"
```

This would output something like

> `line 15: map[$name]: Name Boo not matched`

if the user entered the name `Boo`.

Comment: Consider `exec run` if there's no other commands after, and those error messages need `>&2`.  But yeah, the `case` was exactly my first thought.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Bash shell, have a closer look at this line. There is no `readinput()` function defined so this fails:

```
$name = readinput(Enter name:)
```

Also, variable assignment cannot have whitespace on either side of the `=`. Assignments should not be prefixed with the `$` character. maybe try this instead:

```
echo -n "Enter name:"
read name
```

Also, as @AdminBee alludes to, be sure to add the shebang at the beginning of your script

Comment: `read -p 'Enter name: ' name`, or, if you want to output the prompt with `echo`, at least output it to standard error with `echo -n 'Enter name: ' >&2`. See e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336983