# Gzip verbosity goes to standard error

Tags: gzip, stderr

When I want to redirect any verbose output I usually do the following,

```
[arif@arif test]$ rsync -v /home/arif/storage . 1> stdout
[arif@arif test]$ cat stdout 
storage

sent 177 bytes  received 35 bytes  424.00 bytes/sec
total size is 88  speedup is 0.42
```

But when I do the same thing with `gzip` it creates different result,

```
[arif@arif test]$ gzip -v something 1> stdout 2> stderr
[arif@arif test]$ cat stdout 
[arif@arif test]$ cat stderr 
something:    0.0% -- replaced with something.gz
```

Why verbose output of `gzip` goes to `stderr` instead of `stdout`? This is very problematic for scripting as at the end of the script, an error file is checked and if anything found on the file, a cleanup process is done.

Question is ,

- Why verbose output of `gzip` goes to `stderr` instead of `stdout`?
- How can I overcome this?

Comment: [Do progress reports/logging information belong on stderr or stdout?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/331611/22142)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually better for gzip to print the diagnostic output to stderr, because otherwise you wouldn't be able to distinguish diagnostics from data (in the case of `-c`).

Each program is free to send its messages wherever it likes; [gzip sends them to stderr](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=gzip.git;a=blob;f=gzip.c;h=e6a7761591ea7e844dded1dce39f41db026aa061;hb=HEAD#l1060)

```
1060     /* Display statistics */
1061     if(verbose) {
1062         if (test) {
1063             fprintf(stderr, " OK");
1064         } else if (decompress) {
1065             display_ratio(bytes_out-(bytes_in-header_bytes), bytes_out,stderr);
1066         } else {
1067             display_ratio(bytes_in-(bytes_out-header_bytes), bytes_in, stderr);
1068         }
1069         if (!test && !to_stdout)
1070           fprintf(stderr, " -- %s %s", keep ? "created" : "replaced with",
1071                   ofname);
1072         fprintf(stderr, "\n");
1073     }
```

The workaround would be to deal with each utility on its own terms and expect the specific gzip message on stderr, or omit the `-v` option.