# Is this a bug in fsarchiver --version

Tags: variable, command, version

I learned that in order to capture the output of a Unix command one should use something like

```
RESULT=$(command in question)
```

I want to capture the version of `fsarchiver` to the variable `RESULT` because the former option `-z` of `fsarchiver` has been deprecated. One should use `-Z` instead for version 0.8.4 (the one used under Ubuntu 18.04 LTS). In order to apply the right compression level in my script, it has to distinguish the current version of `fsarchiver`.

So I tried this:

```
$ RESULT=$(fsarchiver --version)
fsarchiver 0.6.22 (2016-02-13)
$ echo "${RESULT}"

$
```

so this one just returns an empty line. However I can determine the version of `ls` this way so I am sure to not have completely misunderstood capturing the output of a command to a variable in a bash script:

```
$ RESULT=$(ls --version)
$ echo "${RESULT}"
ls (GNU coreutils) 8.25
Copyright © 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Lizenz GPLv3+: GNU GPL Version 3 oder höher <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
Dies ist freie Software: Sie können sie ändern und weitergeben.
Es gibt keinerlei Garantien, soweit wie es das Gesetz erlaubt.

Geschrieben von Richard M. Stallman und David MacKenzie.
$
```

Why do `ls` and `fsarchiver` behave differently with respect to capturing their results when asking for their versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fsarchiver` writes its version information to its standard error, `ls` to its standard output. Which one is right is a matter of debate; see [Do progress reports/logging information belong on stderr or stdout?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/331611/86440) for some related discussion. `ls` in your case is likely to be the GNU version, and the GNU coding standards [mandate writing version information to standard out](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/_002d_002dversion.html#g_t_002d_002dversion).

You can capture the version using

```
RESULT=$(fsarchiver --version 2>&1)
```

Comment: Stephen, thank you for the explanation and the hint how to redirect stderr to stdout. This solves my problem. Just one question: is there a way to know if a program writes to stderr or to stdout, because just from observing what it writes to the screen, I see no difference.

Comment: Not directly, but you can use a tool such as [`annotate-output`](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/devscripts/blob/master/scripts/annotate-output.sh) to see where output is being written.